# Issue using greater then under case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'am having issue using greater then between two date time while using case when statement. Basically i have a column called "Status" which has rows of "Open","Hold","Close". I have another column as duetime and completedtime.

Below is my Query in SQL server. Can any one help me to find " if duetime is less then the completed time then "overdue" else "not over due" where column statusname in ('Open','Hold')

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN SD.STATUSNAME IN ('Open','Onhold') AND wrd.DUEBYTIME < wrd.COMPLETEDTIME
            THEN 'Over Due'
        ELSE 'Not Over Due'
        END AS 'OVER_DUE_STATUS'
    ,wrd.WORKORDERID AS REQUEST_ID
    ,AU.FIRST_NAME AS TECHNICIAN
    ,wrd.TITLE
    ,CAT.CATEGORYNAME
    ,dateadd(s, datediff(s, GETUTCDATE(), getdate()) + (wrd.CREATEDTIME / 1000), '1970-01-01 00:00:00') "Created Time"
    ,dateadd(s, datediff(s, GETUTCDATE(), getdate()) + (wrd.COMPLETEDTIME / 1000), '1970-01-01 00:00:00') "Completed Time"
    ,dateadd(s, datediff(s, GETUTCDATE(), getdate()) + (WRDS.ASSIGNEDTIME / 1000), '1970-01-01 00:00:00') "Assigned Time"
    ,dateadd(s, datediff(s, GETUTCDATE(), getdate()) + (WRD.DUEBYTIME / 1000), '1970-01-01 00:00:00') "Due by"
    ,AUSR.FIRST_NAME AS Requester_name
    ,MD.MODENAME AS MODE_OF_REQUEST
    ,DPD.DEPTNAME
    ,SD.STATUSNAME
FROM WorkOrder WRD
LEFT JOIN AaaUser AUSR ON AUSR.USER_ID = WRD.REQUESTERID
LEFT JOIN ModeDefinition MD ON MD.MODEID = WRD.MODEID
LEFT JOIN DepartmentDefinition DPD ON DPD.DEPTID = WRD.DEPTID
LEFT JOIN WorkOrderStates WRDS ON WRDS.WORKORDERID = WRD.WORKORDERID
LEFT JOIN StatusDefinition SD ON SD.STATUSID = WRDS.STATUSID
LEFT JOIN CategoryDefinition CAT ON CAT.CATEGORYID = WRDS.CATEGORYID
LEFT JOIN AaaUser AU ON AU.USER_ID = WRDS.OWNERID
```

Comment: I would suggest that you (1) tag the question with the database you are using; (2) provide sample data and desired results; (3) simplify the query -- you only mention a couple of columns, I doubt all the joins are necessary to answer the question.

Comment: As i have mentioned its SQL server. Providing sample data wouldn't be possible  as table contains confidential information. If you could help considering the 3 column i have mentioned would be much appriciated

Comment: Are both columns datetime? What' s your problem / error?

Comment: There is no error, just that when i use comparison operator within case statement the case statement just ignore it.

Comment: You outer join to SD (StatusDefinition) via another outer joined table. Your logic assumes that there is always a row to join. I'll guess that is not a safe assumption.

Comment: Also - learn to debug your own code. You cannot see the values of the columns your logic depends on - how do you intend to figure this out? Just asking strangers on the internet is not an effective approach - which is why you get the requests for more information.

Comment: "Having issue"  What is the issue?  You don't have to post confidential information.  Just post data to reproduce the problem.  VTC

Comment: What is the data type of the DUEBYTIME and COMPLETEDTIME columns?

Comment: In your question you mention 'Hold', but in your code you wrote 'Onhold'. Which is it?

Comment: Are there any NULL values in the COMPLETEDTIME column? What result do you expect for these rows?

Comment: Hi All, i have sorted this out using this code  case when (dateadd(s,datediff(s,GETUTCDATE() ,getdate()) + (WRD.DUEBYTIME/1000),'1970-01-01 00:00:00') <
 GETDATE() and sd.STATUSID in(1,2)) then 'Over Due' .  I was foolish to compare completed date rather then todays date in order to find over due issue . Thanks for your kind co operation every one.

Comment: Can any one tell me how to close this request?

Comment: @Biswa - Post your answer as the answer to your own question. That's completely acceptable to do.

Comment: I have already answered it on Jan 25th.